# Memcached for magento 2.0.4

Tags: magento2, memcached

I am trying to configure memcached to store sessions in magento.i just installed latest stable version of memcached and changed handler and path in php.ini file and env.php but

I am getting  error

Please have look at http://www.crushdeals.com

Please anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

you need to install php module as well.
also probably this will help you to fix it:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/memcache/memcache.html

Comment: I have done already

Comment: ok, do you see module when you type: `php -m`

Comment: could you please also add your env.php part with memcached settings.

Comment: Nop..I can't see it

Comment: 'session' => 
  array (
    'save' => 'memcached',
 'save_path' =>'localhost:11211'
  ),

Comment: I am using php7.0-fpm and varnish (if it may be a concern)